# Data cardinality is ambiguous error in Keras

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I've slapped together a little snip of code that randomly generates house properties.  The houses are marked as like 90% of the time if they meet a certain criteria.  I'm then attempting to feed this into a basic DNN, but this is where it all falls apart. The DNN code is mostly black box to me and I've tried a number of things here, but I can't get it to take my data.

I think the shape of the array is causing the issue.

```
# Imports for DNN
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

# Imports for generating data
import random

class HouseDetails:
    def __init__(self, color, sqrft, rooms, liked):
        self.color = color
        self.sqrft = sqrft
        self.rooms = rooms
        self.liked = liked

Houses = []
X = []
y = []

for numbers in range(10000):
    color = random.randint(0,5)
    sqrft = random.randint(500, 5000)
    rooms = random.randint(0, 5)
    if ((color == 2 or color == 4) and (rooms >2 and sqrft > 2000)):
        liked = random.randint(0,9)
        if(liked):
             liked = 1
    else:
        liked = 0
    Houses.append(HouseDetails(color,sqrft,rooms,liked))

# Split into input (X) and output (y) variables
for House in Houses:
    if(House.liked):
        X.append(House.color)
        X.append(House.sqrft)
        X.append(House.rooms)
        y.append(House.liked)

# Define the keras model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(6, input_dim=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(6, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

# Compile the keras model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Fit the keras model on the dataset
model.fit(X, y, epochs=150, batch_size=10, verbose=0)

# Make class predictions with the model
predictions = model.predict_classes(X)

# Show the first 5
for i in range(5):
    print('%s was %d (we expected %d)' % (X[i].tolist(), predictions[i], y[i]))
```

The error I'm receiving:

```
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 2982
  y sizes: 994
Please provide data which shares the same first dimension.
```

I'm sure the answer is in the error, but I'm very new to a lot of this and I just can't figure this one out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is stall garbage, but the issue is with the "for House" loop.  It should be:

```
# Split into input (X) and output (y) variables
for House in Houses:
    if (House.liked):
        X.append([(House.color), (House.sqrft), (House.rooms)])
        y.append(House.liked)
```